# Activity Feed still displays some English even when in another language

Tags: android-activity, feed, facebook-social-plugins

If you set up the Activity Feed plugin on a webpage in which you have not previously logged onto with the Login button found in the activity feed, the text beside the Login button will always read "Log in to Facebook to see your friends' are doing."

Ex.: My plugin is set to fr_CA however that message still appears in English.

Also, there's missing a "what" between "see" and "friends'."

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Copy the activity feed code to a web page.
2. Change en_US to fr_CA.
3. View results.

[image]